# running multiple instances of a jenkins job on same node

Tags: jenkins

Is there a way to run multiple instances of the same Jenkins freestyle job on the same node. The job takes about 20 minutes. The node has more than enough bandwidth to run 6+ of that job.

Comment: Yes. Read about executors in Jenkins.

Comment: The problem is not increasing # of executors.  The problem is running the same job uses the same work workspace. The job deletes the workspace before starting.  Then clones a tree.  When you have more than one job running builds do not build correctly.

Comment: I did do some more reading and finally found the "right" keywords. I found that checking  "Execute concurrent builds if necessary" is what is needed. That causes jobs to be started with <workspace>@<build#>.

Answer (score 1):

I did do some more reading and finally found the "right" keywords. I found that checking  "Execute concurrent builds if necessary" is what is needed. That causes jobs to be started with @.